# Subdivision Surface Modifier creates a tall pillar?

Tags: subdivision-surface

i put a tiff file as a displacement for a plane, but when i try to subdivise it turns into a pillar, what did i do wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try if another .tiff works?

Comment: Maybe apply the scale (Ctrl A in Object mode)?

Comment: thx taiyo, got it working, turns out i saved the tiff file (from qgis) incorrectly, thx guys!